# Issue restarting the networking service on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, postfix

I bought a new ip address for my dedicated server on Ubuntu 16.04, and I've been trying to set it up, but I just consistently run into one issue; I'm unable to restart the networking service proper, even with the original config. This is what I get through systemctl status networking.service;

```
systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
ifup[24985]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup[24985]: Failed to bring up eth0.
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here are the contents of the interfaces file (I've censored the addresses of course);

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xx.xx.146
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network xxx.xx.xx.0
    broadcast xxx.xx.xx.255
    gateway xxx.xx.xx.254

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address yy.yy.yyy.153
    netmask 255.255.255.255

    post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 yy.yy.yyy.153 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast yy.yy.yyy.153
    pre-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 down
```

I get this error with both the original file (copied over from the .bak file) and the edited file with the new IP. The networking service simply fails to run for an unspecified reason. If I try to ifup eth0 directly, I get the "File exists" and "Failed to bring up eth0" lines. Yet, despite shutting down, the IPs seem to get set properly in the interface configuration; they are properly mapped to the corresponding interfaces (eth0, eth0:0) and the corresponding Apache/Postfix/Dovecot installations also seem to be functional.

Yet when looking through networkctl, this is the result I get;

```
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged
  2 bond0            ether              n/a         unmanaged
  3 dummy0           ether              n/a         unmanaged
  4 ifb0             ether              n/a         unmanaged
  5 ifb1             ether              n/a         unmanaged
  6 eth0             ether              n/a         unmanaged
  7 eth1             ether              n/a         unmanaged
  8 teql0            void               n/a         unmanaged
  9 tunl0            tunnel             n/a         unmanaged
 10 sit0             sit                n/a         unmanaged
 11 ip6tnl0          tunnel6            n/a         unmanaged
```

The interface name is clearly eth0 and not something else. I'm wondering if some kind of dhcp service is interfering or if another service actually manages the interfaces. I don't think that NetworkManager is installed as the only way to get the server to be pingable again after flushing eth0 is to attempt to start networking, but networking still crashes on the same error. What I'm afraid of is that this will cause the server to be unpingable on a hard restart.

Does anyone have advice concerning the issue?

EDIT1: jones0610 asked for the ifconfig -a, here it is for eth0 and eth0:0

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:c3:4e:f2
          inet addr:xxx.xx.xx.146  Bcast:xxx.xx.xx.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:149408 (149.4 KB)  TX bytes:41071 (41.0 KB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:c3:4e:f2
          inet addr:yy.yy.yyy.153  Bcast:yy.yy.yyy.153  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:c3:4e:f3
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Here's what happens in var/log/syslog, could it be an issue with postfix?

```
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix[3583]:  * Reloading Postfix configuration...
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix[3588]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix[3588]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix[3588]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix/master[1773]: reload -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 16 09:26:32 www postfix[3583]:    ...done.
Jun 16 09:26:32 www systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Jun 16 09:26:32 www systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 16 09:26:32 www systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jun 16 09:26:32 www systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 16 09:26:32 www systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: First thing I'd check is to see if your new IP is actually in use on some other machine.  Pinging that IP should return nothing.  I'm also assuming that all your xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 entries are the same.  NIC OK, plugged in to the subnet, etc.  What does ifconfig -a return?  Should be mostly complete, IP, MAC addresses, bcast, mask, etc.  Since eth0 is broken you must be connecting via eth0:0, yes?  Or is eth0:0 settings the problem.  /var/log/syslog may have something interesting in it.

Comment: I doubt the new IP is on another machine, because Namecheap DNS points a domain name towards it. The domain name refers me to the apache instance in HTTP, and it pings properly. ifconfig -a returns me both the eth0 and eth0:0 interface, both seem to be functional, but ubuntu still runs in a "degraded" state as the networking service fails to boot proper. I'll be appending my ifconfig -a for the two interfaces and eth1 in the main question. The server also seems to reboot fine and sets the interfaces fine, but networking doesn't boot properly.